# Hiring a US patent attorney that is able to help with getting patents in the EU and China

Tags: international, attorney

I plan to get patents for my invention in the US, EU, and China.

I am in the US.

Is it common for US attorneys to either have the capacity to help with getting patents in other countries like the EU and China by themselves or have the connections to connect you with attorneys in those countries?

Comment: +1 for being smart enough to hire an attorney.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - many US patent law firms will have relationships with agents and lawyers overseas. Most patent offices require a locally accredited person to do anything other than the mechanics of filing, if that, so a US firm can’t deal directly with a foreign office unless they have someone on staff that is authorized in the foreign country. Larger US firms might have an EPO and/or China qualified practitioner.

They don’t generally refer you to a foreign associate but act as a middle man, doing an initial modification of your US application for the other jurisdictions, advising  you about options and dealing with the associates professional to professional. (We call them “foreign associates” but there is no formal association.)

A foreign attorney or agent might deal with you directly but usually prefer to have the client interfacing done in the home county of the client. Also your local practitioner can help you decide where to file and for what type of protection.